# extract data udp port

Tags: php, ubuntu, udp

I am newbie
I have a device at home which measures electricity consumption and broadcast some of the data as plain text, using UDP and IP I can specify.
I use netcat and can see the data coming through when I specify my own PC at home as target IP.
I'd like to capture the data and extract some values out of it, the structure of the packets is always the same.
Are there any easy to use tools? 
I tried PHP but could not use any of the examples I found so example will be appreciated as well
Roni

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the function [socket_recvfrom](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recvfrom.php)? A small example from the documentation page:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 1223);

$from = '';
$port = 0;
socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 12, 0, $from, $port);

echo "Received $buf from remote address $from and remote port $port" . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: I have seen this example and tried it. I use local Apache server. using sudo netstat -lpn |grep :9999 I can see this answer udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9999          0.0.0.0:*          . When I use Netcat I get data on 9999 but on this example the page just hangs.

Comment: the error on the browser is Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data.

Comment: not many options for mistakes here, but apparently I am making mistake . in the code socket_bind($socket, '127.0.0.1', 9999);.  On Browser http://localhost/index.php. And if I change the content of the file just to echo something, all other code is commented out,  it will. That's the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/yski53pe6tlswb4/index.php

Comment: What port and what IP is the device on?

Comment: The transmitting device? I have no way of knowing. I can get the IP from router but do not know which ports it uses to transmit. I tried debugging, I hang on this line socket_recvfrom($socket, $buf, 56, 0, $from, $port);  If you can debug on your side and you have static ip and open port I can divert the data to you